# Discordpy Selfbot does not join a sever but doesnt raise an error

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

```
import discord
import asyncio
from discord.ext import commands
invite = "https://discord.gg/XXXXX"
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=prefix, description=description,self_bot=True)
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as')
    print(bot.user.name)
    print(bot.user.id)
    print('------')
    await bot.accept_invite(invite)
    for server in bot.servers:
        print(server)
bot.run(usertoken2, bot=False)
```

No error is being raised and nothing is being returned either.
I just can't find my mistake.
I know selfbots are against Discord's TOS but it's not about abusing it but understanding how things work.

Comment: Are you seeing the rest of the output from your `on_ready` event?

Comment: I do.
But nothing is changing.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `accept_invite` anymore due to spam reduction efforts on Discord's part.